# applying mean to data frame

Tags: r, apply, median

I want to apply the running median over 61 units to my whole data frame.

```
df= 13.03.2017 11:42 12:42:00 877401 922800 -5.045 147 14 NA 
    13.03.2017 11:42 12:42:01 877440 922839 -5.045 148 14 504 
    ...
    13.03.2017 14:40 15:40:12 864742 868109 -0.389 149 25 515
```

I used this code:

`df_med<-apply(df, 2, runmed, k=61)`

I get the error:

```
Error in if (a < b) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I already tried to exclude the first line, but the same error appeared.

Comment: Note that `Runmed` is a function to compute the running median, not the mean. Also, which values in your data frame do you want to take the mean/median of?

Comment: Could you reformat the data into an actual data frame? Do `dput(head(df))` or somesuch.

Comment: @user3640617 I need the running median from the last column, but it is quite possible that i need it from the other columns as well. so I,d like to apply the function to the whole data frame.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would make sense to treat this data as a multivariate time series. I have a preference for the library `zoo`, but there are other alternatives.
With good example data apparently not forthcoming I mocked up some of my own. Might be applicable, might not.

```
library(zoo)

# Put together a data frame with a time vector in the first column    
df <- data.frame(x=as.POSIXct(1:10*60, origin="1970-01-01"), 
                 a=c(NA, 1, 6, 4, 2, 9, 4, 3, 1, 2),
                 b=c(2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 6, 9, NA))

# Convert the data frame into a multivariate time series    
df.zoo <- read.zoo(df)
summary(df.zoo)

# Apply a rolling median on the time series    
rollapply(df.zoo, 3, median, na.rm=TRUE, fill=NA)
```

With the presence of `NA` values it's easier to use `rollapply` and pass `na.rm=TRUE` as argument to the `median` function, rather than dealing with `na.omit` or similar methods. `fill=NA` ensures that the length of the series is the same as before.